# ng-table data not showing

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, ngtable

here my question:

I am trying to build a directive in angular, which would use an ng-table inside. I am using mocked data. The problem is that I cannot render data in the table. here is my directive:

```
;(function(app) {
    app.directive('customTables', [
        'NgTableParams',
        function(NgTableParams) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'templates/directives/table_directive.html',
                scope: {
                },
                link: function(scope) {
                    var dataset = [{
                        name: "Moroni50",
                        age: "50"
                    }, {
                        name: "Moroni49",
                        age: "49"
                    }];

                    scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
                        data: dataset
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
})(app);
```

here is the html:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
    <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">{{user.name}}</td>
    <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">{{user.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

here is how I call it:

```
<custom-table></custom-table>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Change the name of your directive to `ngTable`, not `ngTables`

Comment: It's not because of directive name, the problem is that data is empty

Comment: from where you are getting `$data`?

Comment: remove `scope: { }`  and try.

Comment: I removed scope: {} but the result is same

Comment: please paste the complete html, are you using controller as anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
                        data: dataset
                    });
```

with

```
scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
                        scope.data: dataset
                    });
```

and in html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
```

with

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in data">
```

Comment: `scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
                        scope.data: dataset
                    })`  is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scope.data = [{
                    name: "Moroni50",
                    age: "50"
                }, {
                    name: "Moroni49",
                    age: "49"
                }];

                scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
                    data: scope.data
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
                        dataset: dataset
                    });